# Is the linear equation 1.35x + 5.40y = 10.60 in standard(Ax + By = C) form?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning about the forms of linear equations and I am at the standard form. Some sources say, than for example `1.35x + 5.40y = 10.60` is not in standard form while other sources say it is in standard form. Is it in standard form or does it depend on the place where you are using it?
The standard form means Ax+By=C

Comment: There is no standard definition of "standard".

Comment: The term "standard form" is not known outside your particular textbook.  So use the definition in the textbook.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the standard form for a linear Diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ over the integers, you just have to multiply your equation by $20$. Then the result is
$$
27x+100y=212.
$$
A solution is $(x,y)=(-7844,2120)$.